# Versão do IE nas tags

Tags: debate, tags

Uma ideia para agilizar o fluxo das respostas sobre o único navegador dentre os mais usados que não se atualiza automaticamente de forma forçada.

Seria possível remover a tag `internet-explorer` e todos os seus sinônimos, e ter as tags `IE11`, `IE10`, `IE9`, `IE-jurassico`, etc.? Assim a gente economizava tempo tentando descobrir com quais versões o autor de uma pergunta está a ter problemas.

A pergunta que me levou a pensar nisso foi [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13144/ie-nao-mostra-efeito-css-gradient-e-font-shadow-corretamente), porém acredito que não seja difícil encontrar outras sem a menor referência a versão ([basta clicar na tag e sentir a dor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer)).

Comment: Já existem as tags `internet-explorer-7`, `internet-explorer-8`, ..., `internet-explorer-11`, etc. Apenas não são muito usadas. É uma questão de educar a comunidade e editar as questões sempre que o autor informar a versão.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal concordo. Mas acho que eliminar a tag `internet-explorer` obrigaria o autor a informar a versão correta.

Comment: @Renan Talvez, mas algumas perguntas podem ter à ver com o IE, em geral, então a tag precisa ser mantida. A sugestão do Guilherme é boa o suficiente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não acredito que se deva remover tags simplesmente por existirem tags para versões específicas só **para forçar** o autor a fornecer uma informação a mais sobre sua pergunta. Fornecer informações essenciais para obter a resposta da pergunta é uma questão de costume que o autor deve adquirir.

Além disso, mesmo que o autor não saiba, a pergunta pode abranger mais de uma versão e não aquela versão específica que ele está utilizando.

Por exemplo, para a linguagem Delphi temos a tag [delphi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi)
bem como tags específicas de versões como [delphi-xe3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-xe3), [delphi-7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-7), [delphi-6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-6), etc. Eu posso fazer uma pergunta geral "Como faço um hello world (no delphi)?" ou uma pergunta específica "Meu Hello World no Delphi 6 tem comportamento diferente do delphi 7. Por quê?"

Se forçássemos esta regra de existir apenas tags específicas para versões, no exemplo que eu citei, a cada nova versão do Delphi teríamos que adicionar uma nova tag na pergunta "Como faço um hello world no delphi?", ou então eu nunca conseguiria utilizar tags para encontrar a pergunta.

Não vejo motivos para proibir o uso conjunto das duas tags (geral e específica). Contudo, a tag para versão específica deveria, na minha opinião, ser utilizada principalmente quando a pergunta faz referência a uma característica específica daquela versão.